# patchValue returning only values of the last index

Tags: arrays, angular, foreach

I have an issue while looping through and array, I'm getting all the index from this array correctly but when I use angular **patchValue** it updates all the inputs with the last index values and not with their respective values as shown :

[image]

I want every input to have theirs, for example, first input values should be "1" (left input => longueur) and "1" (right input => quantity)

[image]

I tried with **.forEach** but no success

**CODE SAMPLE**

**component.ts .forEach**

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.requiredFields();
    this.service.checkExistQuot().subscribe(res => {
          this.quotDetails.forEach( (myArray, index) => {
              this.dropForm.patchValue({
                longueur: this.quotDetails[index].longueur,
                quantity: this.quotDetails[index].quantity
              })
             console.log(index);
          });
    });
  }
```

**HTML, input example**

```
<div class="products">
  <div class="d-flex flex-row" *ngFor="let products of selectedDiam;let i = index">
      <input class="number" formControlName="longueur" value="" (change)="postQuotationDatas(products.part_id)" type="number">
    </a>
    <input class="mb-1 flex1 checkbox" type="checkbox">
    <a class="tac flex1"></a>
    <a class="flex1 mb-1">
      <input class="number" value=""  formControlName="quantity" (change)="postQuotationDatas(products.part_id)" type="number">
    </a>
    <a class="flex1"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz example?

Comment: @David https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oagrkm , here's the stackblitz example ( check console ), *ngFor isn't working for the moment, trying to fix it

Comment: Your `quotationDetails` value is incorrect, it needs to be : `quotationDetails = [
    {longueur: "1", quantity: "3"},
     {longueur: "1", quantity: "3"},...`

Comment: @David thank's, it's updated

Comment: You either need multiple formGroups (one for each quantity/longueur pair), or different form control names if you want to only have 1 form group. Have a look there: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jqiddt for example with multiple form groups (1 per quotation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you only have one form group,`dropForm`, with 2 controls: `quantity` and `longueur`. Even though you have multiple html inputs for `longueur` and `quantity`, they are share the same reference in the component

So, with your `forEach` loop, you are actually patching all your controls for each iteration. That's why you have the same value for all your controls, which is the value for the lasst object the loop went over.

### Option #1

A possible solution is to have multiple form groups, like in this [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jqiddt)

**component.ts**

```
//dropForms initialisation
this.quotationDetails.map(() =>
{

let group = this.formBuilder.group(
  {
    longueur: [''],
    quantity: [''],
  });
  this.dropForms.push(group)
}

this.quotationDetails.forEach( (myArray, index) => {
        this.dropForms[index].patchValue({
          longueur: this.quotationDetails[index].longueur,
```

**component.html**

```
<div class="d-flex flex-row" *ngFor="let products of quotationDetails; let index=index"> 
    <form [formGroup]="dropForms[index]"> <!-- 1 form group per quotation -->
```

### Option #2

The other solution, to have only 1 formGroup, is to give dynamic control names

**component.ts**

```
//Initialisation of dropForm
this.quotationDetails.forEach((val, index)=>
{
  group[`longueur_${index}`] = '';
  group[`quantity_${index}`] = ''
});
this.dropForm = this.formBuilder.group(
  group
)       

//Patch
this.quotationDetails.forEach( (myArray, index) => {
    let patchValue = {};
    patchValue[`longueur_${index}`] = this.quotationDetails[index].longueur;
    patchValue[`quantity_${index}`] = this.quotationDetails[index].quantity;
    this.dropForm.patchValue(patchValue);
```

**component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="dropForm">
    <div class="products">
    <div class="d-flex flex-row" *ngFor="let products of quotationDetails; let index = index">
    <a>
      <input class="number"  formControlName="longueur_{{index}}"  value="" type="number">
```

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kwrkkg)

Comment: Sorry for the late answer @David , this is a perfect solution for my problem, thank you for the clear explanation

Comment: No worries, glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

Use FormArray and wrap inputs in arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Example add FormControl to FormArray with FormBuilder:

**FormArray** - A FormArray aggregates the values of each child FormControl into an array.

**in componenent ts:**

```js
const EMPLOYEE_FORM = {
  firstName: ['', Validators.required],
  lastName: ['', Validators.required],
  isActive : [false, Validators.required]
}

const COMPANY_FORM = {
  employees: new FormArray([], [Validators.required])
}
```

```js
export class AppComponent  {
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.fb.group(COMPANY_FORM);
  }

  get employees(): FormArray {
    return this.form.get('employees') as FormArray;
  }

  addEmployee() {
    const employee = this.fb.group(EMPLOYEE_FORM);
    this.employees.push(employee);
  }
}
```

**in html**

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of employees.controls; let i = index;">
  <form [formGroup]="item">
    <input type="text"  formControlName="firstName" class="form-control" placeholder="FirstName">
    <input type="text"  formControlName="lastName" class="form-control" placeholder="LastName">
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" formControlName="isActive">
  </form>
</div>
<button (click)="addEmployee()">add new employee</button>
<div *ngIf="employees.length > 0">
  {{employees.value | json}}
</div>
```

See this link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/add-input-to-formarray-with-frombuilder

Comment: I don't want to add more inputs, I want to set the values returned from json ( second img ) OnInit